# How to notate a subtraction of a matrix columns with a vector?

Tags: matrices, notation

According to matrix algebra, I cannot subtract a vector from a matrix, because they don't have the same size.

[image]

I want to notate that every column of $R_i^t$ is subtracted by vector $R_f^t$, but I don't want to either merge them into 1 matrix, nor change the vector to matrix in order to emphasise the nature of the variables.

Comment: You want to subtract the same vector from all columns of the matrix, right?

Comment: Yes. I thought of looping each column and then do concatenation but I have no idea how to do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given matrix $\mathbf A \in \mathbb R^{n \times p}$, we can subtract vector $\mathbf b \in \mathbb R^n$ from all $p$ columns of $\bf A$ via $\color{blue}{\mathbf A - \mathbf b {\bf 1}_p^{\top}}$.

Comment: According to this, my notation is not wrong, is it?

Comment: You didn't form the outer product by right-multiplying by a vector of $1$'s.